# Recover from wrong Wi-Fi password on Arduino Yún

Tags: wifi, arduino-yun, wireless

I'm trying to customize my Arduino Yún to work as an access-point (or hotspot) for providing services to clients directly connected and, alternatively, to work as a client on a wireless network for downloading resources from the Internet.

The access to such a wireless network is gained after the user submits a network SSID and password in the web control panel provided by Yún.

How can I recover from a user submitting a wrong password? At the moment the Yún stays stuck without any connection, and thus is unreachable via SSH to attempt any recover.

Comment: Perhaps if you posted your code, we could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I came out with a button connected to one of the digital input pins and a sketch that, using the bridge to communicate with the "Linux part" of Yún, restores original values in the configuration files and reboots the whole controller.

After the reboot completes the Arduino Yún is accessible again through the Wi-Fi network "Arduino Yun xxxxxxxxxx".

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option is to provide a serial console interface which will either give full access to the OS (pipe through *Console*) or a menu driven interface that sends instructions to the main chip (through *Bridge*).

The user would then connect to the USB interface and use a terminal program to access the configuration in whatever way you have chosen.  This could either be via options within your installed sketch, or by uploading a special sketch through the USB connection.

Comment: The fact is that the Arduino board will be in a box, and the only channel available will be the wi-fi. I basically would like to replicate the behaviour described in [link] (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardYun?from=Products.ArduinoYUN) , for the WLAN RST button pressed for more than 5 seconds.

Comment: You could always solder wires from the switch to your Arduino such that if after 15 mins you are still not connected to the net. Reset the WiFi by pulling that pin low ( I think)